# kubernetes service getting auto deleted after each deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod, azure-aks

We are facing an unexpected behavior in Kubernetes. When we are running the command:

`kubectl apply -f my-service_deployment.yml`

It's noticed that the associated existing service of the same pod getting deleted automatically. Also, we noticed that when we are applying the deployment file, instead of giving the output as the "deployment got configured" (as its already running), its showing output as "deployment created".. is some problem here?

Also sometimes we have noticed that the service is recreated with different timestamps than we created with different Ip.

What may be the reasons for this unexpected behavior of this service?

Note:- it's noticed that there is another pod and service running in the same cluster with pod name as "my-stage-my-service" and service name as my-stage-service-v1.  will this have any impact?

Deployment file:-

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-service
  labels:
    app: my-service
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-service
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-service
        image: myacr/myservice:v1-dev
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: my-az-secret
```

Service file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-stage-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-service
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 8880
    targetPort: 8080
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with your manifest files. The problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: @Jonas,  is there any chance of conflict between the other service which is running "my-stage-service-v1" for the deployment "my-stage-service"?

Comment: use a different namespace and there should not be a conflict

Comment: just watch the state in the cluster and find out what is happening when you apply changes

Comment: So even if the service name is different in the same namespace, it can make the issues like this. because we have other microservices with same content of deployment file and services, but didnt see any issue and there is no conflict with the names for these as i explained.

Comment: Run `kubectl version` and make sure client and server versions match

Comment: its in AKS- Azure kubernetes Service

Comment: Do you check if there are enough resources in your cluster nodes? I mean the CPU and memory.

Comment: @CharlesXu Yes.. it  is there. its not affected in anyways for other micro services.

Comment: What does the event logs show? I think it would give some helpful info.

Comment: Do you solve the problem?